# Need help with Det of Matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

I need your help in this exercise:

$\det B\ne0, \det A=0$, and I need to calculate
$\det((A+B)^2−(A−B)^2)$

I need your help please!

Comment: Have you tried expanding those products already?

Comment: Yes, and i didnt succed